# qlikview currency conversion salesforce example

Tags: mysql, qlikview

I'm new here and downloaded the salesforce project as reference for a problem I've been having.

I have various currencies and wish to throw them into an input box as per the salesforce example, so that conversion is performed on a table box column on the fly. I also want EUR to be default.

I've inferred some points and read through the official Qlikview pdf tutorial for others but I just can't seem to figure one thing out: I get what's going on in the 'currency' script - it's creating several tables and referencing the previous one each time for clarity based on whether the initial table has several currency rows (both web view and a quick download available @ http://eu-b.demo.qlik.com/detail.aspx?appName=Salesforce.qvw).

What I don't get (probably amongst other things) is why in the properties of the currency input box, under pre-defined values it has:

=concat(distinct CURRENCY,';')

I simply want my currency data to be separated as new lines as one would expect from an inpux box (and how it is currently displaying with salesforce) but because I'm concating my values, they're separated by ';' as instructed.

Once this is done I need to think about converting the values to EUR in my main table, so that it displays the amounts in the currency selected from the input box.

Please be as informative as possible if you've the answer as I'm new here - provide me with actual resources I can learn from if you can't be bothered to type much. Also I'm currently trialing Qlik and therefore cannot open external files easily. If I complete my first project with it (looking good so far), I'll go ahead and purchase a personal license. Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you altered what was checked under the 'Value List' header in that same Properties dialog? I've downloaded the Salesforce app and my dropdown correctly displays each currency option as it's own item. The `Predefined Vales in Drop-down` radio button should be selected.

Comment: @bdiamante Yes I've changed the item constraints and double-checked- here is a screenshot of my current setup: http://i.imgur.com/lQ0Bu4g.png

Comment: Under the `Settings for Selected Variable`, what happens when you change that to one value instead of your delimited list. I believe if you reset the 'value' to USD or just one of the other currencies, the next time you make a selection from the dropdown that value will be stored.